# Java 8 Stream, get string length due to several conditions

Tags: java, loops, java-stream

I have a program that calculate the occurrences of `d`, for example `s = "dda"` and `n = 10` I will repeat those until I get `s.length = 10` e.g `ddaddaddad` the `result = 7d`.

I have done this in basics loop:

```
int count = 0;
String s = "dda";
int n = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
     if (s.charAt(i) == 'd')
         count++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < n % s.length(); i++) {
     if (s.charAt(i) == 'd')
         count++;
}
return count * (n / s.length());
```

Thus I'm trying to do that using streams, and I'm wondering how I can do it?

What I already achieved:

```
return s.chars().filter(x -> x == 'd').count() * (n / s.length()) + (n % s.length());
```

I know The problem in that last part `(n % s.length())` I need to check if the index contain `d` or not, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need to add to your calculation is to substring s by the reminder and repeat the count: -

```
    return s.chars().filter(x -> x == 'd').count() * (n / s.length()) +
            s.substring(0, n % s.length()).chars().filter(x -> x == 'd').count();
```

**EDIT**: if, for some reason, you dislike the oldfashined substring, you could replace it with stream of ints from 0 to the reminder:

```
    return s.chars().filter(x -> x == 'd').count() * (n / s.length()) +
            IntStream.range(0, n % s.length()).filter(i -> s.charAt(i)== 'd').count();
```

However, the question reminas whether this all-stream version is more comprehensive/readable.

Comment: I'm was thinking that I can do that without substring, e.g some methods in stream, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might just be looking for a simpler logic if I get your question right. It could be as :

```
private int characterCountWithRecurrenceWithinLimit(String string, int limit, char c) {
    // repeat string unless its shorter than the limit

    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(string);
    while (sBuilder.length() < limit) {
        sBuilder.append(string);
    }
    // keep the string within the limit
    String repeatedString = sBuilder.toString().substring(0, limit);
    // count the character occurrence
    return (int) IntStream.range(0, repeatedString.length())
            .filter(i -> repeatedString.charAt(i) == c)
            .count();
}
```